# Trace in Azure Bot Service

Tags: debugging, trace, azure-bot-service

I'm following this step to enable tracing in Azure Bot App Service https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html

However, my trace does not appear in the log stream.
I can see a bunch of other logs here.

I also tried "#define TRACE" at the class with the code

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Entering the About View");
```

Am I missing anything?

> My Azure Web App setting: https://pictr.com/images/2019/06/25/5BHthA.png
>
> My Log stream: https://pictr.com/images/2019/06/25/5BHszI.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the changes in the portal to enable it; you'll want to use the `Microsoft.Exensions.Logging` namespace. Add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` package (version appropriate for your project).

Then add logging for azure (`AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics`) where you setup your host:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            });
```

Then make sure your class implements ILogger. You can see an example of that in the Core bot sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/f2f94f4d642bbdfc9719f33b44a2c51aa70e2aa0/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Bots/DialogBot.cs#L25).

Then just do your logging in the method you wish:

```
Logger.LogInformation("This is my test.");
```

Here's some more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Can use below to log to App Service's Logstream as well if using Starter Bot at https://github.com/martinkearn/Bot-Starter-Template/:

```
  ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger,

 logger.LogError($"Exception caught on attempting to Delete ConversationState : {e.Message}");
```