# How to register Azure bot conversation traces

Tags: azure, bots, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker

I have an Azure Bot Web App created from QnA Maker.
I'm using it in Teams and using the test in QnA and web Chat from Azure.

I was trying to get the answers that the user made to the bot. But in the Insight resource I'm only able to see Custom Events for each conversation that a user began. It's like the insight is not registering traces at all.

How can I set the bot or either the insight to register traces? 
thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750872/trace-in-azure-bot-service/56962678#56962678

Comment: I have a hunch that you're looking for the trace activities in the App Insights traces table. Is that correct? Do you see the trace activities represented in the custom events table?

Comment: @KyleDelaney exactly i was looking for trace activities in the trace table. In the custom event table I'm only able to see each conversation that is created.

Comment: Among other things, "trace" is a type of Bot Framework activity. Is your bot/client sending trace activities? Or when you say trace do you mean something else? Can you edit your question to include sample code and screenshots?